# How to activate VT-x on a Acer Aspire E1-571G?

Tags: windows, laptop, bios, virtualization, vt-x

How to activate the hardware virtualization an this laptop if on the BIOS i don't have any options...It's very simplified ( the only tabs on the BIOs are those:

[image]
[image]

I searched and the processor supports VT-x ...

Answer (score 3):

Download the official Microsoft virtualisation checker tool. This will confirm whether VT-x is enabled.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=592

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your processor supports but its seems as far i can see your bios dont, look for the model of your  motherboard of your manufacter webpage and download the latest bios update.

Comment: Actually she's half right - his processor supports it as per [the intel ARK](http://ark.intel.com/products/71465/Intel-Core-i3-3120M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_50-GHz). A bios update won't do much good since they're locked down. They talk about this on [acer's forum](http://community.acer.com/t5/Notebooks-Netbooks/Advanced-BIOS-settings-for-Aspire-E1-522/td-p/151267/page/2) but I can't in good faith suggest something that dangerous without testing it myself.

Comment: Maybe try [requesting for a BIOS mod](https://www.bios-mods.com/)