# How to activate VT-x on a Acer Aspire E 15 E5-573G-34QR?

Tags: laptop, bios, virtualization, acer-aspire

How to activate the hardware virtualization on this laptop if the BIOS menu does not have any options? It's very simplified. Similar to [How to activate VT-x on a Acer Aspire E1-571G?](https://superuser.com/questions/805830/how-to-activate-vt-x-on-a-acer-aspire-e1-571g) Can't use that answer : on windows 8 the [tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=592%20windows%20tool) does not run.

Need android SDK emulator & virtual box to run.
Processor : Intel Core i3-4005U (1.7GHz, 3MB L3 cache)

```
>  PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64 
>  PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel 
>  PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6 
>  PROCESSOR_REVISION=4501
```

Info from securable:

> Hardware Virtualization
>
> This processor does offer advanced hardware support for
>   virtualization. However, while running under a 64-bit version of
>   Windows this program cannot execute its 32-bit kernel code to
>   determine whether Intel's VMX virtual machine extensions are being
>   locked on, locked off, or neither. Since there's a chance that your
>   system's BIOS may be deliberately disabling support for hardware
>   virtualization (some do) you should re-run this program, if possible, 
>   with administrative privileges under a 32-bit version of NT, XP, or
>   Vista. That will allow SecurAble to run a bit of kernel-mode code in
>   order to determine exactly what's going on. (Note that you can also
>   poke around in your system's BIOS to see whether you're able to find
>   any references to "hardware virtualization" or "VMX", etc.

Any other safe way? Wish they had an advanced BIOS for those who need it.

Comment: If the BIOS has no option to enable it, then it cannot be enabled, what processor do you have specifically?

Comment: @ramhound answer updated, need more info? the processor supports it, just need a way to enable it safely :)

Comment: Sigh no ubuntu WIFI support, and now this http://askubuntu.com/questions/652199/wireless-not-there-on-a-aspire-e-15 need to search a good dev laptop, less costly than a Mac

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. One workaround is to turn off the Hyper-V and disable memory integrity. To do this

1. Open a Command prompt with administrative rights (Admin) and type

   ```
   bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
   ```
2. Open

   > Windows Security > Device Security > Core Isolation Details

   and turn memory integrity off

After turning memory integrity off, you should be prompted to restart your machine. I was trying to run Docker Toolbox and it worked after I followed those steps.